# get the current url with any parameter like # in php

Tags: php, url

I want my current page url in php my page have no query string like

```
e.g http://example.com/questions/ask/#/shop/12/67777
```

i get http://example.com/questions/ask/ but from # the url is break

Answer (score 1):

The browser doesn't send to the server the URL datas after the `#`, there are only used client-side (considered as an achor). But you can use Javascript to get these (with `location.hash`).